# flutter add bottom navbar on specific pages

Tags: flutter, dart

In my `main.dart` I have this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(App());
}
```

Inside another file called `App.dart`:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "MasterChef",
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => LoginScreen(),
        '/HomeScreen': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        '/ProfileScreen': (context) => ProfileScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to add a sticky bottom nav bar in my application, across all the screens excluding the login page.

Is there a ready-to-use package which I can use or do I need to write custom code. If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pageview with bottom navigation bar. Just add the pages you want the button nav bar to show in the page view....

In login.dart

We are going to use two scaffold....
Like this
Dont mind the code is because I am in mobile

```
Class Login extend statefull{
//add all neccessary thing here 

bool authIsTrue =false;

Logingscreen(){
Return scaffold(

// here is the login is successful then it will change the state of authistrue, I hope you get the idea


)
}

Pageview(){
ruturn scaffold(
body pageview(
Children [

// here add those pages you want the button nav bar you to show. Note... then you can now use bottom nav bar in this page..
]
)
);

}

Widget(Buildcontext context){
return authsIsTrue ? Pageview() : loginscreen();
}
```

Comment: so that'll all go in `app.dart`?

Comment: I am on mobile and my network is hell slow, I would have shown you a sample code.... mean while, just use page view, add all the pages and exclude the page you want the bottom nav to show.... that is all

Comment: I have update the answer, you will understand what I am talking about there

Comment: I'll just check-in with you, should I discard my `app.dart`. Because all my routes are currently written there. And I'll implement all my routes in `login.dart`?

Comment: No.. no need to discard app.dart... you will do the login it Loginscreen...

Comment: So when the auth is okay for login it will change the state of the bool... look at the code very well you will understand what I means...

Comment: Have you get it ?

Comment: Hi, @gbenga after some tweeking it worked. thanks a lot for checking in

Comment: Hi @gbenga. Although your code works fine in simple application when the app grows I kinda mess up. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: I will give you a link to my github, I did not push the full code to github, but that aspect you need, the full function is there...

Comment: Yeah that'll be helpful

Answer (score 0):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-use-flutter-to-build-an-app-with-bottom-navigation

and an endless number of other tutorials about bottom navigational bar in flutter. Just use google